# Webpack - $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, webpack

I am moving an existing webapp from requirejs to webpack.

I have an issue with the way jQuery is imported/shimmed.

In my bundled js, I am getting a `$ is not a function` error from within the bootstrap javascript.

When I `console.log($)` from within the bundled script it reveals an empty object: `object {}`

I am assuming that this is because nothing is exported from jQuery as it would traditionally set $ to the window object and be done.

Some research pointed me to use webpack plugins (see my webpack.config.js below) but this doesn't appear to solve the issue.

Is there anything wrong in my setup?

Thanks

My webpack.config.js:

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    //devtool: 'source-map',

entry: ['./mobile.js'],
resolve: {
    root: "./js/",
    alias: {

        jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.9.1',
        underscore: "libs/lodash-1.0.1",
        //backbone: 'libs/backbone-1.0.0',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone-0.9.10',
        bootstrap: "libs/bootstrap-2.3.1",
        ......
    }
},
resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
},
output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
],
module : {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: "text" },
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" }
    ]


   }
}
```

The offending compiled bundle code:

```
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(__webpack_provided_window_dot_jQuery) {/* ===================================================
     * bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.1
     * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#transitions
     * ===================================================
     * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     * ========================================================== */


    !function ($) {

        console.log($); //THIS GIVES THE EMPTY OBJECT {}
      "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


      /* CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (http://www.modernizr.com/)
       * ======================================================= */

      $(function () { //$ IS NOT A FUNCTION OCCURS HERE

        $.support.transition = (function () {
.........
.........
```

Comment: When you view the source of your  page, is the jQuery.js file included?

Comment: In the console, what happens if you try `$.fn.jquery`? This should display the version of jQuery you are using if it is being loaded

Comment: Any `console`errors?

Comment: Has this been resolved. I am having the same issue.

Comment: I am seeing this error, but when I run `$.fn.jquery` I do see "1.8.3" and I can access elements using `$`. Did anyone find an answer? I am using webpack `4.27.1`

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `exports-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev exports-loader
```

And config:

```
{
   include: require.resolve('libs/jquery-1.9.1'),
   loader: 'exports-loader?window.jQuery'
}
```

---

**OR** the problem can be in that `ProviderPlugin` doesn't read `jquery` alias, so try:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "libs/jquery-1.9.1",
    jQuery: "libs/jquery-1.9.1",
    "window.jQuery": "libs/jquery-1.9.1"
})
```